# Update a device owner managed android app silently (in kiosk mode)

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, device-policy-manager

I have created a device owner app. It can turn an app installed already into Kiosk Mode, I am trying to update the kiosk app remotely, not from playstore, but it's not getting updated. Could anyone please help me with some pointers?

Comment: Is the app you want to update on Play? If yes you will need to use one of Google's API to manage updates. The Android Management API allows to set a [SystemUpdate](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#SystemUpdate) window to control when app and system updates happen.

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the response, but I want to update it remotely.

Comment: Create your own server add your apk over there than download apk from your server and install using adb command but it needed root device.

Comment: The Android Management API allows you to do everything remotely, it's a Cloud API.

Comment: @UpendraShah, no the device is not rooted.

Comment: Okay, So there is another way to install app using intent but is need user interactions.

Comment: @UpendraShah, Could you please be more descriptive, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to host your apk on your server and then download it based on any conditions that you specify. You can then use this code to update your app.

```
public static boolean InstallAPK(Context context, String apk_file_name) {
        try {

            File apkfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + apk_file_name);
            if (apkfile.exists()) {

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(apkfile);

                PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                        PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                params.setAppPackageName(context.getPackageName());
                // set params
                int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

                int c;
                while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, c);
                }
                session.fsync(out);
                in.close();
                out.close();
                session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                sessionId,
                new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),
                0);
        return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
    }
```

Comment: What is createIntentSender ?

Comment: I tried that code it is not showing any error, it is returning true but apk is not installed?